# Crackle sound due to flow of charges

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-current

Why is a crackle sound generated when charges flow between surfaces? Does this energy comes from the loss in potential energy of electrons?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the crackle you hear in an audio system occurs because the wire connections between components are imperfect. Each connector consists of metal pieces which are pressed firmly together by spring pressure, but dirt and oxide buildup on those metal surfaces results in not one good solid connection but hundreds of ones with just tiny contact areas that start and stop working at random. Each start and stop will yield one little crackle. This can be minimized by using connectors with gold-plated surfaces.

Comment: But my question was regarding the sound generated due to flow of electrons. What excatly causes this sound

Comment: the look up "shot noise."

Comment: @nielsnielsen I looked it up and it doesn't appear to have much to do with actual physical sound (it's a statistical noise). I think OP is asking why a spark makes the noise it makes.

Comment: Yes what causes noise in a spark.

Comment: I think it's related to vibration in air due to sudden movement of electrons but not sure about it